# InnoDB initialization warnings

Tags: mysql, docker, alpine-linux

I am using docker on Windows 10 to build full web stack (php, nginx, mysql 8). Using docker compose.

**docker-compose.yml** 
Here I am using services to build web applcation. But i will show you only mysql service

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    db:
        build: services/mysql
        container_name: db
        image: projects/laradock_mysql:latest
        env_file: ../.env
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./storage/data:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            - sites

networks:
    sites:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 10.100.36.0/24
```

**MySQL DockerFile**

```
FROM mysql:8

COPY conf/my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

**MySQL config file**

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

**Output log when docker-compose up**

```
2020-06-18T04:40:52.552867Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2020-06-18T04:40:55.549460Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(15, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.568116Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(16, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.582720Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(17, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.600203Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(18, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.614565Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(19, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.630446Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(20, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.649691Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(21, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.666272Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(22, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.682022Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(23, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:55.698763Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(24, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:56.379410Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012579] [InnoDB] fallocate(25, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE | FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, 0, 16384) returned errno: 22

2020-06-18T04:40:56.384741Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
```

Thanks for a Help!

Comment: `perror 22` -> `OS error code  22:  Invalid argument`. Undoubtedly Windows doesn't support the fallocate. Look for the innodb system variable that disables this/uses an alternate.

Comment: @9inelemons Have you solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue and solve it going to Docker preferences > General and unchecking the "Use gRPC FUSE..." option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why? what does that?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa It will let the docker use the Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) server. For example, if you use Windows and are reading file shared with a Linux container, it could cause a problem when of Filesystem reading that will be corrected unchecking this option.
You can learn more about it by reading the following links:
 - https://www.docker.com/blog/deep-dive-into-new-docker-desktop-filesharing-implementation/
 - https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/12/docker-desktop-windows-fuse/